# converting struct to general message format to be passed to UDP

Tags: c++, sockets, struct

I have a `C++ struct` for an `update packet` to be exchanged between servers, and another `struct` to implement information about `neighbor`s, and a `vector` of `struct neighbor` is inside `update packet`.

```
struct neighbor;
struct update_packet {
    uint16_t num_update_fields;
    uint16_t port;
    uint32_t IP;

    vector<struct neighbor> neighbors;

    update_packet(char * IPstr, int port) :
        num_update_fields(num_nodes),
        IP(IP_to_int(IPstr)), port((uint16_t) port)
        { };
};

struct neighbor {
    uint32_t IP;
    uint16_t port;
    int16_t nil;
    uint16_t server_id;
    uint16_t cost;

    neighbor(char * IPstr, uint16_t port, uint16_t server_id, uint16_t cost) :
        IP(IP_to_int(IPstr)), port(port), nil(0),
        server_id(server_id), cost(cost) { };
};
```

I want to exchange this struct in `general message format` (like `IP datagram`, for example) through `UDP` sockets and read the information in the message on the receiving end.

How can I achieve this? Is my design for the `struct`s a poor design for my purpose?

Comment: converting a signed int to an unsigned one without checking is risky, why not have the `neighbor` constructor take the same types that neighbor uses?

Comment: I'm not a fan of this design.  You can't simply take the address of an `update_packet` and send that down the wire, because the vector is there.  I would rather have an `update_packet` and a variable number of appendages, each one a `neighbor`.  As it is now, you're going to have to `memcpy` all the stuff out of this structure and the `vector` in to yet another buffer, and send that other buffer down the wire.  Blech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking about is *serialization*.  At it's simplest, if you have a POD type and know that the machines at both ends are the same type you can just cast and send:

```
struct Foo {
  uint32_t a;
  uint16_t p;
};

Foo f { 1, 2 };
sendto(targetFD, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&f), sizeof(f), 0);
```

Your structure couldn't be used this way because of the vector.  The data in a vector is dynamically allocated so it isn't laid out with the rest of the structure.  If you need a variable length field like this, an array (or a std::array) along with an indicator of the number of elements would be useful.

Casting structures like this is fast but not really portable.  If you want to be able to pass to other languages or platforms you would prefer a serialization format.  Google's Protocol Buffers (https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and several other serialization libraries are designed to allow this.

Comment: Thanks. So If I use an array, can I send it to another server just with `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&f)`, and read it on the receiving side by casting the message to `struct update_packet`? I thought it would involve bit manipulation and complex low-level operations, but the solution looks like simply casting types from `struct update_packet` to `const char*` and then back to `struct update_packet`. Is it so?

Comment: Yes. If you are in control of the machines at both ends and they are the same architecture then you can reasonably cast on both ends if you replace your vector with an array. If there are a fixed number of neighbors then you can be done there. If you have a variable number of neighbors then you will need an array large enough to hold the maximum number. If you just send sizeof(update_packet) at that point you will get all of the empty cells at the end of the array, so you may want to do a bit of extra work to include the number of elements and determine the total size without the empty cells.

Comment: I don't have a default constructor for `struct neighbor`, and with this I will have trouble initializing an array of `struct neighbor`. Should I get rid of constructors for the two `struct`s and fill them in manually? Do functions as members affect the size of `struct` instance? I'm asking this because the structs should be in `general message format` and they only can use fixed memory size.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more c++ style serialization and deserialization is desribed in this article - https://rodgert.github.io/2014/09/09/type-driven-wire-protocols-with-boost-fusion-pt1/